# Python Scrapy Scrape brand logo name and logo image url

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-pipeline

I have a python scrapy - scraper used to scrape an ecommerce site at the moment it is unable to scrape the brand logo name - and brand logo image url -   I dont need to download the actual logo - previous working code is

```
        l.add_xpath("manufacturer", ".//img[contains(@class, 'product-brand-logo')]/@src")
        l.add_xpath("manufacturer_logo_image_url", ".//img[contains(@class, 'product-brand-logo')]/@src")
```

The source code for that section from the website is

```
<div class="product-price-details">
<div class="product-details">
<div class="product-brand-logo visible-xs visible-sm product-brand-logo--flex">
<a href="/vogue/_/a33-1" manual_cm_sp="PDP%20brand%20click-_-Vogue-_-D161">
<img class="product-brand-logo__image " data-src="https://media.testdom.com/asset/en/brand/large/vogue.jpg" alt="Vogue" title="Vogue" />
</a>
<div class="js-tooltip product-brand-logo__tooltip" data-tooltip="true">
<a href="/vogue/_/a33-1" manual_cm_sp="PDP%20brand%20click-_-Vogue-_-D161">
Browse our full Vogue range</a>
```

Please can someone help correct the previous code which was working until now - to reflect the changes made in the site

When the scraper is running no error is shown - it just doesnt scrape the required data and columns are blank for both

Thanks

Comment: If you analyze by yourself you will find the problem

Comment: Could you please provide a [mcve]? While it can be deduced that `l` is an `item loader`, it's not clear from the way you asked your question. Also, how did you try to debug your code? What have you tried and what failed? You should also read some of the [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) help pages (see `1.`).

Comment: Thank you for your kind replies Plz note I am not a scrapy programmer or have any experience coding in scrapy - I am using the scraper only however from time to time if I run into issues I can identify changes in the source code and update the items.py and it fixes it. On this I tired changing in xpath product-brand-logo to product-brand-logo__image    as this is the only difference I can see - But this did not scrape the required data or provide any syntax error

Answer (score 1):

You can surely scrape manufacturer logo through:

```
l.add_css('manufacturer_logo_image_url', '.product-details .product-brand-logo .product-brand-logo__image::attr(data-src)')
```

But I'm not sure why in the previous example `manufacturer` was scraped from the image src. If you need manufacturer name, get it from the image title:

```
l.add_css('manufacturer', '.product-details .product-brand-logo .product-brand-logo__image::attr(title)')
```

Comment: thanks I tried adding the lines but I am getting IndentationError: unexpected indent

Comment: I fixed the error and scraper runs now it is scraping the manufacturer logo image url But not the manufacturer name

Comment: Edited, use the second line :)

Comment: I added both lines as I need both brand name and logo image url from 2 columns in the export csv thanks

Comment: hi sortas can you please clarify your comment use the second line as i mentioned I have tried it but am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Previously I made a typo, so both lines were collecting 'manufacturer_logo_image_url', so I fixed the second one and now it collects 'manufacturer'.

Comment: thanks I tried with the updated but it is still not getting the manufacturer only the url is being scraped

Comment: `::attr(title)` this part in the second line should collect img title, and can't collect url by any means. check your code, or check the site, maybe layout has changed.

Comment: hi sortas the source code is exactly the same and in my code apart from the lines mentioned in the above question I can't see any other ref for logo or get the manufacturer name from the title